# ISNULL - ON clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm trying to use the `ISNULL`, `COALESCE` or `CASE` on this `ON` clause but it gives me an error.

> 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'.

I need to check one date from one table between two dates from other one but if the date doesn't exist on the second table then use the previous date.

```
talbe1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.code = t2.code 
AND ISNULL(cast(dateadd(d,-1,t1.UtcFinishTime) as date) BETWEEN t2.TransactionFirstDate and t2.TransactionLastDate,cast(dateadd(d,-2,t1.UtcFinishTime) as date) BETWEEN t2.TransactionFirstDate and t2.TransactionLastDate)
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect because `ISNULL` needs to be part of the statement as it returns the value; and not the entire statement, so you're likely after something like:

```
AND ISNULL(
           cast(dateadd(d,-1,t1.UtcFinishTime) as date), 
           cast(dateadd(d,-2,t1.UtcFinishTime) as date)
          ) 
     BETWEEN t2.TransactionFirstDate and t2.TransactionLastDate
```

Or using a `CASE` functionality.

But I'd advice you for performance sake to make a check before hand and then have a specific query for either situation.

Answer (score 1):

Could not check it but off the top of my head, below query may help-

```
SELECT * 
from table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
     ON t1.code = t2.code AND 
     CASE 
       WHEN dateadd(day,-1,t1.UtcFinishTime) is null 
       THEN cast(dateadd(day,-2,t1.UtcFinishTime) as date) 
       END 
     BETWEEN t2.TransactionFirstDate and t2.TransactionLastDate
```